# Как вытащить объект по id из Dao?

Tags: java, база-данных

Есть User'ы с полем "id" (1, 2 , 3).
Они все помещены в Dao с помощью ArrayList.
Нужен метод, который выводил бы их по id.
Допусти ввели id "1" и нам выводит User'а с этим id.

Comment: Используйте `Map<IdType, User>` для хранения информации о пользователях с доступом по ключу id  вместо списка `ArrayList`

Comment: @NowhereMan к чему такие извращения? почему у User'а не может просто быть поля Id которое и будет primarykey ??

Comment: При чем тут извращения??  Если в дао (некий промежуточный слой, тот же кеш) есть список и нужен доступ по ключу, следует использовать мапу.  Это никак не связано с тем, что id у юзера / в базе должно быть первичным ключом.

Comment: @Wlad да, есть поле id. Мне нужен метод который будет их по этому id выводить по одному. ArrayList объязательное условие. Метод строится в отдельном классе Service

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял Вам нужен метод который принимает список User'ов и id, и возвращает пользователя из списка с id равному переданному.
Если предположить что класс User выглядит так:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName, lastName;

    public User(Long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

То можно написать подобный метод:

```
public static User findIn(List<User> userList, Long id) {
    return userList.stream().filter(u -> u.getId().equals(id)).findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

Вернёт null если не найдёт пользователя с нужным id.
Тестовая программа:
private static final String[] firstnames = { "John", "Jim", "Anya", "Dave" };
private static final String[] lastnames = { "i", "dont", "know", "any lastnames" };

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Создание списка пользователей
    List<User> userList = IntStream.range(0, 4)
            .mapToObj(id -> new User((long) id, firstnames[id], lastnames[id]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(Finder.findIn(userList, 1L)); // User{id=1, firstName='Jim', lastName='dont'}
    System.out.println(Finder.findIn(userList, 5L)); // null
}
```